# Phonegap, inAppBrowser not display "done" button

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I works with phonegap, one of my flows need to open external site, I use inAppBrowser for it. And here I am very confused, I want that in new windows will be some buttons, like DONE, BACK.... After some search in th internet I found that inAppBrowser provide this functionality, but not in my case. I  don't see any buttons or bars. What I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Android or iOS? I am using it for iOS and I can see back, done buttons. Can you show us the code which is opening InAppBrowser?

Comment: I trying base example from phonegap site, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Comment: We're having similar problems, specifically with PDFs: multiple projects we've tested will all open inAppBrowser, but the configurations don't apply, and there are no buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of phonegap are you using? 
Have you set location to 'yes' when you initialize the InnAppBrowser?

Enabling this should show the 'Back', 'Forward' and 'Done' buttons on Android.

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: I'm using PhoneGap 3.3 and testing on iOS7 - neither the toolbar nor the done button are appearing for me, either.

Comment: Same here. Phonegap 3.3.1 iOS 6 no toolbar or location bar present, regardless of options.

Comment: What does 'location=yes' does it works if we dont write it